# Can you reheat cooked calamari without thawing?

Tags: seafood, frozen, defrosting, squid

Can you reheat cooked calamari without thawing first? If I take it from the freezer and boil it, how long will it take to reheat the calamari?

Comment: I think you're asking whether you can cook/reheat it without thawing? Defrosting is a synonym of thawing. I've edited accordingly; please fix it if I got it wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure you want to heat it to boiling. Maybe longer in a cooler water temperature.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to reheat calamari without thawing first, I would suggest boiling for one to two minutes, depending on piece size, longer if you are using larger pieces. Conversely you can cover the calamari with boiling water and let it sit for a little bit longer than one to two minutes, I would also suggest that you heat thoroughly, better safe than sorry. I am also not entirely sure the texture will be optimal. Good Luck.